# jQuery - parameter of ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm studying the following code and I'm wondering how the callback function gets its parameter:

Doing the request

```
getData( "hg34j3", loadData);
```

Callback function

```
function loadData(param) {
    var data = param;
    ......
 }
```

get data

```
function getData(anId, callback) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url + "abc/" + anId,
        type: "GET"
      });      
      request.done(callback);
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? Sorry, but I'm not quite sure of what you're trying to ask in your question.

Comment: As explained in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), jQuery will call the callback with three arguments, `data, textStatus, jqXHR` - your callback can then use whichever of those arguments it needs.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy the word callback has no braces like loadData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
    request.done(callback)
```

Doesn't exactly call the callback function. Rather it passes a reference to the callback function to the `.done` method of the jQuery Deferred object. Within that object is the actual call to the callback function. If you were to look at the source code for jQuery, you'd see that when the Ajax completes, it does indeed call the function with a parameter of the Ajax results.